# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'jqGridRender' not found

Tags: php, jqgrid

One of my project I need to display records in tabular format for that purpose I am using `Guriddo jqGrid` PHP to display records, but I am getting error like:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'jqGridRender' not found....."

I am using `PDO` for connecting database.
Can any one help me out to overcome with this error?

Please have a look on my code:

```
require_once 'jqgrid/jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."jqgrid/php/PHPSuito/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once ABSPATH."jqgrid/php/PHPSuito/DBdrivers/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
        // Write the SQL Query
        $sql = 'select member_id,members.full_name, email, mobile, member_type, state_name, city_name, location_name, IF(status=1,"YES","NO") as status, IF(validation_success=1,"YES","NO") as validation_success, profile_picture, date_added, date_updated, last_seen, isloggedin';

        $sql .= " from members ";

        $grid->SelectCommand = $sql;
        // Set the table to where you add the data
        $grid->table = 'members'; 
        // set the ouput format to json
        $grid->dataType = 'json';
        // Let the grid create the model
        $grid->setColModel();
        // Set the url from where we obtain the data
        $grid->setUrl('manage_member_grid.php');
        // Set some grid options
        $grid->setGridOptions(array("rowNum"=>100,"sortname"=>"full_name","sortorder"=>"asc","height"=>150,"multiselect"=>true,"hoverrows"=>true,"rowList"=>array(10,20,30,40,50,100),"shrinkToFit"=>false,"width"=>1140,"height"=>500));//

        //Set Primary Key for row
        $grid->setPrimaryKeyId("member_id");

        // Hide fields
        $grid->setColProperty("member_id", array("hidden"=>true));

        //Change some property of the full_name field
        $grid->setColProperty("full_name", array("label"=>array("Name")));
        $grid->setColProperty("full_name", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));

        //Change some property of the email field
        $grid->setColProperty("email", array("label"=>array("Email")));
        $grid->setColProperty("email", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));

        // Change some property of the mobile field
        $grid->setColProperty("mobile", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));//,"width"=>300,"lable"=>array("Added Date")
        $grid->setColProperty("mobile", array("label"=>array("Mobile")));

        // Change some property of the member_type field
        $grid->setColProperty("member_type", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));//,"width"=>300,"lable"=>array("Added Date")
        $grid->setColProperty("member_type", array("label"=>array("Member Type")));

        // Change some property of the State field
        $grid->setColProperty("state_name", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("state_name", array("label"=>array("Satate")));

        // Change some property of the City field
        $grid->setColProperty("city_name", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("city_name", array("label"=>array("City")));

        // Change some property of the Address field
        $grid->setColProperty("location_name", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("location_name", array("label"=>array("Location No")));

        // Change some property of the date_added field
        $grid->setColProperty("date_added", array("formatter"=>"date","formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"d/m/Y h:i a")));//,"lable"=>array("Added Date")
        $grid->setColProperty("date_added", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("date_added", array("label"=>array("Added Date")));
        $grid->setDatepicker('date_added');
        $grid->setColProperty('date_added', array("editable"=>false)); 
        // Change some property of the date_updated field
        $grid->setColProperty("date_updated", array("formatter"=>"date","formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"d/m/Y h:i a")));
        $grid->setColProperty("date_updated", array("label"=>array("Last Update")));
        $grid->setColProperty('date_updated', array("editable"=>false)); 

        // Change some property of the status field
        $grid->setColProperty("status", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("status", array("label"=>array("isActive")));

        // Change some property of the validation_success field
        $grid->setColProperty("validation_success", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("validation_success", array("label"=>array("isEmail Validate")));

        // Change some property of the profile_picture field
        $grid->setColProperty("profile_picture", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("profile_picture", array("label"=>array("Profile Picture"),"formatter"=>"js:formatLinkImages"));
        $grid->setColProperty('profile_picture', array("editable"=>false)); 
        // Change some property of the last_seen field
        $grid->setColProperty("last_seen", array("formatter"=>"date","formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"d/m/Y h:i a")));//,"lable"=>array("Added Date")
        $grid->setColProperty("last_seen", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("last_seen", array("label"=>array("Last Seen")));
        $grid->setDatepicker('last_seen');
        $grid->setColProperty('last_seen', array("editable"=>false)); 
        // Change some property of the isloggedin field
        $grid->setColProperty("isloggedin", array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn","eq","ne","le","ge","gt","nc","bw","bn","ew","en"))));
        $grid->setColProperty("isloggedin", array("label"=>array("isLoggedin Now")));
        $grid->setColProperty('isloggedin', array("editable"=>false)); 

        // Enable toolbar searching
        $grid->toolbarfilter = true;
        $grid->setFilterOptions(array(
        "stringResult"=> true,
        "searchOperators"=>true
        ));


        // We can put JS from php
        $custom = <<<CUSTOM
        /*function formatLinkMember(cellValue, options, rowData) {
        return "<a class='button' href='#login_form' id='login_pop' onclick='getMemberDetails("+rowData.member_id+")' >"+rowData.full_name+"</a>";
        //return "<input type='button' value='somevalue' onclick='some_function'\>";
        }*/
        function formatLinkImages(cellValue, options, rowData) {
        var path = "'"+rowData.member_id+"', '"+rowData.profile_picture+"'";
        return '<a class="button" href="#login_form" id="login_pop" onclick="javascript:getImagesDetails('+path+');" >'+rowData.profile_picture+'</a>';
        //return "<input type='button' value='somevalue' onclick='some_function'\>";
        }

        CUSTOM;
        // Let set the code which is executed at end
        $grid->setJSCode($custom);


        //add on double clicl event (This will take to the View Records)
        $ondblclick = <<<DBLCLICK
        function(rowId, iRow, iCol, e)
        {
        if(rowId)
        {
        // this refers to grid
        $(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow',rowId,{});
        }
        }
        DBLCLICK;
        $grid->setGridEvent('ondblClickRow',$ondblclick);

        // add a custom button via the build in callGridMethod
        // note the js: before the function
        $buttonoptions = array("#pager",
        array("caption"=>"Pdf", "title"=>"Export to Pdf", "onClickButton"=>"js: function(){
        jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('excelExport',{tag:'pdf', url:'manage_member_grid.php'});}"
        )
        );
        $grid->callGridMethod("#grid", "navButtonAdd", $buttonoptions);

        // Enable navigator searching
        $grid->navigator = true;
        // Set which buttons should be visible
        $grid->setNavOptions('navigator',array("add"=>false,"edit"=>false,"del"=>false,"view"=>true,"excel"=>true,"recreateForm"=>true));
        // Enjoy
        $grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know which version of Guriddo Suito PHP is used. In the latest versions (can't remember which one)  autoloader class is used.

Maybe you can try to load the render class insted of jqgrid one i.e replace

```
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."jqgrid/php/PHPSuito/jqGrid.php";
```

with this one

```
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."jqgrid/php/PHPSuito/jqGridRender.php";
```